# How to lower Intellij Idea system resources usage? (Music freezing, other programms lagging while programming in Idea)

Tags: intellij-idea, cpu-usage

I use IntelliJ IDEA for Java on Windows7.

Problem: I can't listen to music or watch videos, while coding in Idea. The music/video plays brokenly or freezes for 1-3s. And the most depressing thing is that it happens not only when I build/run/deploy my projects, but also when I'm just typing anything in the editor!

Hardware: AMD A10-6800k + 8Gb RAM.

Question: Is there any way to limit IDEA's system resources usage? Or what should I do, to enjoy programming and music at the same time?

Please help, I'd really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What might help is if you set the CPU Affinity of the IntelliJ IDEA process to use fewer processor cores in the Task Manager. That way one or more cores are left over for other processes.

Another option would be to lower the priority of IntelliJ IDEA or increase the priority of your music application. Also from the Task Manager.